# How to make a menu button similar to the one in the Path app?

Tags: android, animation, user-interface

Path is a social networking application that allows you to create a small social group to be intimate with rather than a large one like Facebook.

Something that really impresses me about this app is the UI. They have a signature menu button, which is a circle that spins releasing smaller circles as menu options.

I love the way it look and want to know how to do menu/UI animations in general. Could anyone direct me to sucha tutorial/article?

Thanks.

Here is the Path app: [Path](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.path&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wYXRoIl0.)
Here is some app that just has the menu animation (no source, unfortunately): [Path UI anim demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.littleorc.android.anim&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5saXR0bGVvcmMuYW5kcm9pZC5hbmltIl0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android-path-like-button/ Hope this helps, it is underdevelopment, as you cannot see bounce effects yet, but i have forked it and I'm working on further more furnishings.

Comment: Oh, excellent. This should help me, although I'll have to lookup how to get it from SVN. Any chance you have it on GitHub?

Comment: It's very simple, download svn, link is provided in the same page too. Open command prompt if in Windows and navigate to your folder and type in the "svn checkout" command and it will be imported.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are just using a some custom made drawables for their button backgrounds and tweened position and rotation animations. Please see this resource for information on Android UI animations:

[Android UI Animations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html)

Comment: Oh, right. I was looking for a more general animation guide. Thanks!